# How to use if else in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms-2017

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE validate
    @blockID VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @blockID = (SELECT blockID FROM block WHERE blockID = @blockID)
        PRINT 'exists'

    IF @blockID != (SELECT blockID FROM block WHERE blockID = @blockID)
        PRINT 'does not exist'

END
```

When input the wrong one blockID, the 2nd if conditions does not work.

Comment: @HoneyBadger sorry, forgot that :), i mean like this now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `EXISTS`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE validate
   @blockID VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT blockID FROM block WHERE blockID = @blockID)
      PRINT'exists'
   ELSE
      PRINT'not exists'
END
```

Comment: @ImNewBtw, remember to mark Zhorov's answer as the correct answer, by selecting the tick mark next to his answer...